# Trouble passing props to imported component

Tags: reactjs

I have a "main" component which imports two other components, which contain a form each, and I'm having trouble passing some values which I get from an API call in the main component.

This is an example of what's happening on the "main" component with one of the imported forms:

```
user_id = null;
email = "";

componentDidMount() {
    get(`user-data/`, this.token).then((response) => {
        this.user_id = response.user_id;
        this.email = response.email;
        // Doing a console.log at this point shows both values are assigned properly
        // And that they exist
    }).catch((error) => notify.notifyError(error.message));
}

<UserForm
  email={this.email}
  id={this.user_id}
></UserForm>;
```

Edit: I'm including the API call logic since I believe it has something to do with the issue.

```
export const get = async (url, authToken) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${url}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `${BEARER} ${authToken}`,
      },
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error();
  }
};
```

On the `UserForm` component:

```
id = null;
email = "";

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = props.id;
    this.email = props.email;
    // Doing a console.log here shows both props are empty
    // Trying to use either of them from here on out breaks the page
}
```

I assume the issue has to do with the components rendering before the value gets assigned, but I'm not entirely sure about it.

Why aren't the props received properly on the imported form, and how can I make sure they are?

Edit 2: Waiting for props to be set on `componentDidUpdate` works, but operating the way I need to creates and endless loop of execution of `componentDidUpdate`

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.id) {
      console.log("props are set!");
      this.getData();
    }
  }

  getData() {
    get(`user-data/${this.props.id}`, this.token)
      .then((user) => {
        // This creates and endless loop of updating
        this.setState({
          ...user.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => notify.notifyError(error.message));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main component do like this

```
state = {
    email: '',
    user_id: null
}

componentDidMount() {
    get(`user-data/`, this.token).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            email: response.email,
            user_id: response.user_id
        })
        // Doing a console.log at this point shows both values are assigned properly
        // And that they exist
    }).catch((error) => notify.notifyError(error.message));
}
```

and in your userform print your props like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    console.log('this.props', this.props);
    console.log('prevProps', prevProps)
}
```

Comment: This actually did the trick, I just had to adjust in order to avoid endless loops when calling `getData` inside `componentDidUpdate`, but a quick look at documentation helped solve the issue. Thanks both to you and @tsecheukfung01, I'll pick this one as an answer since it's the closest to the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since this two values are not managed by `state`, when the values varies, it won't triggered re-render. Hence, the props are not getting the up-to-date value. I suggest using state to handle those 2 values

```
constructor(props){
   this.state = {
    user_id = null;
    email = "";
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
    get(`user-data/`, this.token).then((response) => {
        console.log('response works fine?', response)
        this.setState = {
          user_id = response.user_id;
          email = response.email;
        }

        // Doing a console.log at this point shows both values are assigned properly
        // And that they exist
    }).catch((error) => notify.notifyError(error.message));
}

render(){

<UserForm
  email={this.state.email}
  id={this.state.user_id}
></UserForm>;

}
```

In your `UseForm` component, there is no need to place it in state unless you want to do further modification. I suggest directly test them in `render` method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render(){
   const {id, email} = this.props
   return (
     <div>
        {id} and {email}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: I have tried using states but had the exact same issue (props being empty on the imported component), thought it might have to do with their async nature so I switched to variables instead, that's why I wasn't using states in the OP.

Comment: it should be ```this.props.id```. You can check the modified answer.

Comment: Still not working, passing hardcoded props works fine (doing something like `<UserForm id={1}></UserForm>`), but using the values obtained from the API call return empty on the other component.

Comment: You can test whether the response works fine by using ```console.log``` before setting state. Check my modified answer